# underscore.js _.every() and _.some() with no callback

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

For an assignment, I´m working on re-creating underscore´s _.every() and _.some() functions to pass a set of specs. However, I´m unable to get the functions to work with no callback function. Here is the spec (spec is the same for both functions):

```
 it('should work when no callback is provided', function() { 
 expect(_.some([true, true, true])).to.be.true; 
 expect(_.some([true, true, false])).to.be.true; 
 expect(_.some([false, false, false])).to.be.false; 
}
```

And here is the code:

```
// Determine whether all of the elements match a truth test. 
197   _.every = function(collection, iterator) { 
198     return _.reduce(collection, function(trueCheck, item) { 
199       if (!trueCheck) {return false;} 
200       if (item === true || iterator(item)){ 
201         return true; 
202       } 
203       else return false; 
204     }, true); 
205   }; 
206 

207   // Determine whether any of the elements pass a truth test. If no iterator is 
208   // provided, provide a default one 
209   _.some = function(collection, iterator) { 
210     var isAllFalse = _.every(collection, function(item) { 
211       return !iterator(item); 
212     }); 
213     if (isAllFalse === true) { 
214       return false; 
215     } 
216     return true; 
217   }; 
218
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Hi Felix, I´m not completely sure, but my functions as written do not pass the spec checking whether or not they work when no callback function is provided.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to debug your code. What have you done in that regard? Either way, look at `item === true || iterator(item)` and think about what it does.

Comment: My suggestion: determine at the top of the function if a callback has been provided. If not, provide a default one, ie `function(item) { return !!item }`

Comment: @Brennan: Just `Boolean` will do the thing :-)

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-30

Comment: Additionally, think very carefully about which comparison operator you want to use (`===` vs `==`)

Comment: @Bergi, you certainly could, but I think `!!` is perfectly clean, and it is significantly faster (by a wide margin): http://jsperf.com/boolean-vs-double-bang

Comment: @Brennan: I did not mean to pass `function(item) { return Boolean(item) }`, I did mean to pass `Boolean`. You're right, `!!…` is faster (and maybe even more idiomatic) than `Boolean(…)`

Comment: Ah, i see what you are saying. Not a bad solution by any means, but just like you said, it departs from idiomatic JS. Good feature to know about, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use plain Javascript:

```js
var _ = _ || {};

_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
  for (var i = collection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!collection[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

_.some = function(collection, iterator) {
  for (var i = collection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (collection[i]) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(_.every([true, 'is', 1])); //true
console.log(_.every([true, 'is', false])); //false
console.log(_.some([null, '', 0, false])); //false
console.log(_.some([true, 'is', false])); //true
```